Issue with WiFi and Ethernet after Installing a Library on Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu 20.04
I recently installed a library on my Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 20.04. After rebooting the system, I lost access to WiFi, and the WiFi option has disappeared from the settings menu. I also tried connecting an Ethernet cable, but that didn't work either.
Is there a way to boot into recovery mode or any other method to troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

Which library? Please [edit] and update your answer.
